# Change the keys for changing windows gone in Mavericks

Tags: keyboard, macos

When I got my Mac-Mini, I've changed the cycle-through windows key from <kbd>⌘`</kbd> to <kbd>⌘0</kbd> (since on the Hungarian keyboard layout I should press <kbd>⌘⌥ű</kbd>, and never could remember which one is it from 5 other key.)

In Mountain Lion this option was still present, but now it is missing from Mavericks. I can't find it in the Keyboard & Input section anywhere. The entry for <kbd>⌘⇥</kbd> is also missing. This became problematic only now, because I only noticed now, that it clashes with a key combination in Microsoft Outlook. (I don't know if this problem come with the update, or had it before.)

Can anybody help how can I change this option or how to restore it?
I would like to set it to <kbd>⌥⌘⇥</kbd> and <kbd>⇧⌥⌘⇥</kbd> as I did it once before. (Or <kbd>⌃⌘⇥</kbd> should be more comfortable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my installation of 10.9 the shortcut can still be changed from System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to next window:

[image]

I don't think it was ever possible to change command-tab to another shortcut though.

Comment: I am an idiot. Or my Mac is trolling me. Either way it is still there.
However I clearly remember that it was possible to change cmd-tab, and that is what I was looking for, and that is why I didn't find it. Although a human memory is too fragile to base it only my memories, so a confirmation on that is needed.

Comment: @AdamL.S.: you can switch the functions of modifier keys (control, command, alt and caps lock) with each other, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys (https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm8pq0g99sp4stx/modifier_keys.png). This is a way to change command-tab to e.g. alt-tab or control-tab. Of course, it changes every other command-* shortcut to e.g. alt-* too, so it might not be what you’re looking for.

Comment: @pauld.waite thank You, but that wasn't what I was looking for. As I remember, I believe it was possible to change cmd+ tab keys explicitly. Besides, I was concerned about switching the windows of an app, not the apps them self, as I changed that key once, which was not suitable any more.

Comment: @AdamL.S.: gotcha. I think VMWare lets you use cmd-tab in place of alt-tab in Windows guest VMs. I mention it in case you’re remembering that and confusing it with re-mapping cmd-tab on Mac OS X (although I doubt that’s the case).